# Sum total in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

There is 3 doctypes A , B and C and there is amount of these values

What I have tried:

i.e.

```
Type_Number amount                        Sum= 2200       
A_12939848   2100
A_28387348   100
c_10000233   300
```

now i want sum of these values depend on Doctype

like this

```
Type_Number amount                        Sum= 2500       
A_12939848   2100
A_28387348   100
c_10000233   300
```

i use formulas for this

i select running total and select amount field and also fix A and C type like this `employees.type in ['A','C']` then i save with amount_formula name
then i drag this field on report

after this i create shared formulas and then i write this

```
shared tax as number
shared tax2 as number


tax=({#amount_formula})
tax2=tax2+tax
formula=tax
tax=0
i drag this on report

and second formula


shared tax2 as number
formula = tax2
tax2=0
```

but the sum display 2200 and i want 2500

any solution?

Comment: if you are grouping ['A', 'B'] I can imaging 'C' is not added to the sum

Comment: oh sorry i mean A and C .. i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Don't create running total for every simple calculations instead try following way.

create a formula `@Extract` and write below code:

```
Type_Number[1];
```

Now create a group using this formula `@Extract` and place the fields in details.

For overall summary take report footer summary and for individual sum take group footer summary

Comment: i dont understand your answer

Comment: Type_Number[1]; will extract the first letter of the field Type_Number now when you group the with that formula you will get group by employee type. Now when you place the fields your data will be group as per employee type and take summary as required using insert summary option for amount

Comment: follow the steps in answer and you will get the result

Comment: when i write Type_Number[1]; this in formula editor error display when i select basic syntax  " A statement is expected here " and when i select crystal syntax it shows "the remaining does not appear to be a part of formula" ??

Comment: yes.. now i write like this @type_number[1]; beacuse in type_number i create formula {VwIbad2.doctype}&'-'&{VwIbad2.acdocno} and then i save with type_number name  & drag this field on report ..

Comment: and i create group @extract group and place all field on details section .. but how to get sum?

Comment: Right click on the field and go to insert summary and select summary for all group as required